# Loop through a nested python dictionary/list loaded from yaml

Tags: python, dictionary, nested, yaml

Ok, this is probably stupid. Basically i'm trying to loop through my nested yaml-file and do stuff with for example every key-a value in my list. I have read alot and i'm able to loop through a nested dictionary without the list but I don't wan't to use unique key's for the nodes.

This works:

lev-0a:
  lev-1a:
    node1:
     key-a: '1'

```
node2:
 key-a: '2'
```

But when i'm trying to iterate a nested dict with "list" objects it fails.

Yaml:

```
lev-0a:
  lev-1a:
    - key-a: '1'
      key-b: '2'
      key-c: '3'
      key-d:
        level-2:
          - key: 'a'
          - key: 'b'
          - key: 'c'

    - key-a: '7'
      key-b: '8'
      key-c: '9'
      key-d:
        level-2:
          - key: 'x'
          - key: 'y'
          - key: 'z'
```

Print settings from python:

```
{'lev-0a': {'lev-1a': [{'key-c': '3', 'key-b': '2', 'key-a': '1', 'key-d': {'level-2': [{'key': 'a'}, {'key': 'b'}, {'key': 'c'}]}}, {'key-c': '9', 'key-b': '8', 'key-a': '7', 'key-d': {'level-2': [{'key': 'x'}, {'key': 'y'}, {'key': 'z'}]}}]}}
```

My code:

```
env.settings_file = env.setting_path + '/settings.yaml'

def load_settings(settings=env.settings_file):
    try:
        with open(settings) as stream:
            data = yaml.load(stream)
            return data
    except IOError as error:
        print ('File error: ' + str(error))


def dev(settings=load_settings()):

    for k, v in settings['lev-0a']['lev-1a'].iteritems():
        print v['key-a']
        # do stuff with every key-a value
```

Error:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

If I do this:

```
for k, v in settings['lev-0a']['lev-1a'][0].iteritems():
    print k,v
```

I will get:

```
key-c 3
key-b 2
key-a 1
key-d {'level-2': [{'key': 'a'}, {'key': 'b'}, {'key': 'c'}]}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*This alone* should have raised an error: `settings['lev-0a']['lev-1a'].iteritems():`. In your code, the value pointed to by `['lev-1a']` appears to be a `list`, not a `dict`, so calling `iteritems()` on it is very suspect.

What you seem to have been looking for is something like:

```
for dict1a in settings['lev-0a']['lev-1a']:
    print dict1a['key-a']
```

That prints both [`key-a`] values found inside of the two dicts from the `['lev-1a']` list. Does this answer your question at all? I have to admit I am not certain I fully understand your question. Feel free to elaborate and I'll edit accordingly.